# How to configure Spring 4 controller for unique session for each browser

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I'm trying to configure Spring MVC so that each browser session or tab has it's own session.  Can this be done?

A snippet from my controller:

```
@Controller
@Scope("session")
public class TestController {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationService as;

private User user = new User();

@RequestMapping(value="/testIntegration")
public String getIntegration(Model model) {
    logger.debug("user: " + user.toString());

    if(!as.authenticateUser(user, sessionTimeout)) {
    .
    .
    .
```

The class User is a POJO.

When 'testIntegration' is accessed first time all values are null.  This is expected.  'as.authenticateUser(user, sessionTimeout))' sets the correct values.  On the next access values are set on User.  This is expected and desired.

If another browser window is opened and attempts to access 'testIntegration' the same populated User object is retrieved from the session.  This is NOT expected nor desired.  A new browser should garner a new session and require a new User object to be created and populated.

I've seen an older thread indicating that a conversation indicator can be implemented by placing the conversation ID on each form of the application.  I'm hoping for a better/different approach via Spring annotations or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way HTTP and browsers work: session identifiers are implemented with cookies, these are shared across all browser tabs. In order to get this you need to pass along unique browser tab identifier along with session id cookie.

Considering your application can contain anchor tag links which client can control/command click (or right click and select open link in new tab) this can be tricky and you will need to make tradeoffs.

One way to do this is to generate a tab-id (for instance UUID) if tab-id parameter is not specified in request, and make sure that its put in all links and submitted with all forms in your application.

Link generation can be affected by wrapping HttpServletResponse (using HttpServletResponseWrapper) and overriding the encodeURL method. And if you're using spring forms taglib or thymelef you can add hidden inputs to forms using [RequestDataValueProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestDataValueProcessor.html).